# запутался в строках на с++

Tags: c++, строки

Всем привет!

У меня есть программа, которая выводит из строки количество в ней цифер.

Допустим строчка `"qwrtt56hhbb055ghjj"`. Соответственно программа выводит `"5 цифр"`.

А как мне теперь найти их сумму? То есть 5+6+0+5+5?

Comment: Необходим код - телепатов здесь нет.

Comment: Хотя бы на русском языке объясните,как это написать. на с++ сам уж напишу

Comment: Функция atoi переводит строку с числом в число. Дальше уже очевидно.

Comment: На русском языке: каждый раз, когда код находит очередную цифру, прибавляйте её к аккумулятору (переменной типа `int`). Не забудьте инициализировать счётчик, за вас язык это не сделает. В конце выдайте значение аккумулятора.

Comment: @Алексей, заводите переменную для результата, скажем типа int, инициализируете её нулем. В цикле находите символы цифр, попутно выполняете `std::stoi` над ними и результат прибавляете к той самой переменной. Ну а после цикла, выводите результат куда вам необходимо.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, ну строго говоря, вопрос про С++ был. За вкрапление CRT-функций довольно неприятные разговоры с начальством/заказчиками бывают.  Лучше не учить такому молодое поколение :)

Comment: про молодое поколение это точно,1 курс,спасибо большое

Comment: @SergeyRufanov специально не писал про вычитание из символа 0x30 :-)

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, здесь проще всего использовать обычные циклы.

Вот демонстрационная программа, которая показывает два подхода в зависимости от того, где  хранится строка.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
{    
    const char *s = "qwrtt56hhbb055ghjj";
    unsigned int sum = 0;

    for ( const char *t = s; *t; ++t )
    {
        if ( *t >= '0' && *t <= '9' ) sum += *t - '0';    
    } 

    std::cout <<  "sum = " << sum << std::endl;
}
{
    std::string s( "qwrtt56hhbb055ghjj" );

    unsigned sum = 0;

    for ( char c : s )
    {
        if ( c >= '0' && c <= '9' ) sum += c - '0';    
    } 

    std::cout <<  "sum = " << sum << std::endl;
}

    return 0;
}
```

В обоих случаях вывод на консоль будет

```
sum = 21
sum = 21
```